# Null value Left Outer Join in Spark

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark

I have two RDD and got the left join

left join `p1.leftOuterJoin(p2)` the result is like:

```
Array[((String, String), (Int, Option[Int]))] = 
Array(((1001-150329-002-0-04624,5060567),(1,None)), ((1002-141105-008-0-01934,10145500),(1,None)), ((1013-150324-009-0-02270,15750046),(1,None)), ((1005-150814-005-0-05885,5060656),(1,Some(1))), ((1009-150318-004-0-02537,5060583),(1,None)))
```

I want to replace all `None` with `0` and get a clean data set like:

```
Array(((1001-150329-002-0-04624,5060567),0), ((1002-141105-008-0-01934,10145500),0), ((1013-150324-009-0-02270,15750046),0), ((1005-150814-005-0-05885,5060656),1)), ((1009-150318-004-0-02537,5060583),0))
```

Basically replace all `(1,None)` with `0` and `(1,Some(1))` with `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the value of the `Option` when `Some` or `0` when `None`, I would implement it with `.map` and `.getOrElse`:

```
a.map { case (k, (_, o)) => (k, o.getOrElse(0)) }
```

The result match the expected one:

```
Array(
  ((1001-150329-002-0-04624,5060567),0),
  ((1002-141105-008-0-01934,10145500),0),
  ((1013-150324-009-0-02270,15750046),0),
  ((1005-150814-005-0-05885,5060656),1)),
  ((1009-150318-004-0-02537,5060583),0))
```